# How can I remove any words with three or lesser characters in a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

Please, I need help with removing any words with three or lesser characters in a string.

Here is my code

```
let text = "The best things in life are free";
let result = text.replace(/^[a-zA-Z]{3}{2}{1}$/, '');
```

My expected result should be:

"best things life free"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this need `regex`, just split with a `space` and `filter` with `length` bigger than 3 and `join` again with a `space`

```js
let text = "The best things in life are free";
let result = text.split(' ').filter(i => i.length > 3).join(' ');

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's now working as expected